# Could not delete Trash.0 folder from external hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, xfce

I am using WD external hard drive and linux OS. I deleted some files in hard disk by mistake I selected those file and just pressed [delete] button instead of [shift+del] in linux. Now it created Trash.0 folder. I tried to delete files using [shift+delete] it gives following error:

Could not delete file "4.6"
Error removing file /media/root/My Passport/Trash.0/expunged/2697747326/usr/include: Directory not empty.

Error removing file /media/root/My Passport/Trash.0/expunged/3073970550/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6: Directory not empty.

I also tried to delete the folder "include and 4.6" but not working I also tried to use command:

sudo rmdir Trash.0
and

sudo rmdir  --ignore-fail-on-non-empty Trash.0 
still not working....

Answer (score 1):

**.Trash-0** folder is created to improve file recovery for external drives.

Whenever you mount an external disk, a **.Trash-*** directory will be created in the "root" directory where files are moved to if deleted from the GUI, like the trash on your desktop.
Take a backup of the files and try to format the hard-disk.

or.....

You need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install secure-delete
```

and then

```
srm -rf /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/
```

Answer (score 0):

First empty the "Trash can", e.g. in nautilus or other FM. The folder should be deletable either immediately or after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

cd to that folder and issue ls -al and check if there are any hidden files

then do rm -rf * to recursively and forcefully remove it

Answer (score 0):

Just boot with a Live Ubuntu 18.04 MATE USB and open the folder leading up to the .Trash-0 folder and also that folder itself as Administrator (you do this by right clicking on the folder and select Open As Administrator) and now you can delete the files :-)